# What is the best practice for VCS structure project wise or platform wise?

Tags: git, github, version-control, architecture

I have recently joined an organization and facing a problem with git repo structure. What is the best approach to keep git repository structure:

1. Complete project in one repository (Front-end (Angular, Html), backend, Android, and iOS in single repo)
2. Create a separate repo for each platform.
   In the earlier organization, we used to follow the second one approach Create separate repo for each platform but in the current one, our architecture engineer told me it's better to keep single repo for all platform.

There are lots of great project example of Single repo per platform on git like:

1. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk
2. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
3. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python
4. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java
5. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node

But I didn't find any example for the famous library as a single repository for multiple projects.

Can anyone explain the exact pros and cons of both approaches and what is the best solution?
If anyone can help me here it is really appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unlick Subversion, which is fine for a single monolithic project, Git works best for small projects.

The Reason is the conflict scope of Git is the whole repository. Before pushing, you have to update the respository. Remote changes usually can be automatically merged, but in case there's a conflict, you have to manually resolve. Keeping a repository small helps reduce the chance of merging.

If you have a big solution, you are better off saving it into multiple repositories. Usually each module/DLL/Visual Studio project is a repository.

See also Professional Git, by Brent Laster

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- **For multiple projects in VCS**, if the projects are related with each other, you’s better manage them in the same repo. Else you’d better manage them in separate repositories (as the projects in firebase you linked).
- **For a project in VCS**, you should **manage it in a single repo** no matter how complicated the project is.

As your situation, all the platforms (for front-end and back-end) are contribute for the same project, so you should manage them in a single repo. If you manage the project in separate repos for different platform, it will reduce the coupling and relations for the project, especially when you need to test for the project level. And for the different platforms, you can manage them in different branches, that's the common manners to version control for a project.

And this is an example [realworld](https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld) for a project developed by multiple platforms.